# How to compose functors with STL?

Tags: c++, stl, composition, functor

The following is possible in STL:

```
int count = count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), bind2nd(less<int>(), 3));
```

This returns the number of elements in v that are smaller than 3. How do compose a functor that returns the number of elements between 0 and 3? I know boost has some facilities for this but is it possible in pure STL?

Comment: There's `std::logical_and`. There's also `std::bind`, which is a better solution to `bind2nd` if you can use C++11. If you can use that, you're better off with a lambda, though.

Comment: C++11 is not fully supported by Visual Studio yet so I'd prefer a C++03 solution. I know about lambdas but I was curious if it can be done without them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean by using the functor composition facilities of the standard library, then no, at least not in C++98. In C++11 you could use `std::bind` for arbitrary composition of functors:

```
using std::placeholders;
int count = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                          std::bind(std::logical_and<bool>(), 
                                    std::bind(std::less<int>(), _1, 3), 
                                    std::bind(std::greater<int>(), _1, 0)));
```

But that doesn't really pay the headache for such a simple predicate.

If C++11 features are allowed, then the simplest way would probably be a lambda, no need to make a complex functor composition (yourself):

```
int count = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int arg) { 
                          return arg > 0 && arg < 3; });
```

But for C++98 *Chubsdad*'s answer is probably the best solution.

Comment: You can remove much of the syntactic cruft by defining custom `less` and friends of the form `struct less_t { template<class T> bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) { return a < b; } } less;`. With a local `using namespace std;` in addition to `using namespace std::placeholders;`, it looks quite a bit nicer: `bind(logical_and, bind(less, _1, 3), bind(greater, _1, 0))`.

Comment: Of course, you can’t beat a lambda for concision and performance. Nor can you beat a functional language; in Haskell you’d write `\ x -> x > 1 && x < 3` or perhaps `liftA2 (&&) (> 1) (< 3)` if you were feeling fancy.

Comment: @JonPurdy But on the other hand *"me just love `std::` everywhere, is make me feel being big C++ developer"*. I would even have dropped the `using std::placeholders`, hadn't it enabled a better formatting of the example without a horizontal scroll bar. In the same way I wouldn't redefine things like `std::less`, which for me would count as additional overhead (even if those templated operators things you suggest are probably useful at other places, too), not in the era of lambdas.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Absolutely. Just adding to the discussion, as in C++ there are often many ways of doing things. I recall, though, that the committee acknowledged the design of `less`, `logical_and`, &c. as a bit of an oversight—you shouldn’t need to specify the template parameter, as it can be deduced if you make just the member function a template.

Comment: @JonPurdy But on the other hand the original `std::less` and friends are from a time when member templates weren't that prevalent, I think. If I remember correctly those were quite a late feature compared to the other template functionality (but I might be wrong). But of course you're right, and they still could have adapted them when composing the standard (which at that point finally had member templates).

Comment: Could you extract the lambda to give it a name, e.g. `in_range`?

Comment: @PeterWood You can make a named variable of the lambda's type (which in the end is just a functor object) by saying `auto in_range = [](...) {...};`, so you can use it then like any other functor or function. But since the type of the lambda is unique and not known until its definition, this only works with `auto` or in other type deduction contexts (like template arguments and thus `std::count_if`). I.e. you cannot return a lambda driectly from a function (or use it as member variable), since you don't know its type beforehand, you would have to use a general `std::function` as wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you ask? I know it's not pure STL, but still..

```
struct InRange
{
    InRange(int x, int y) : mx(x), my(y) { }
    bool operator()(int x)
    {
        return (x >= mx) && (x <= my);
    }
    int mx, my;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(13);
    v.push_back(14);
    v.push_back(18);
    v.push_back(3);

    int count = std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), InRange(0, 3));
}
```

Comment: This is what I'd do, too. I'd name the struct `InRange`. I'd probably delegate to a `Range` class which was being used reused elsewhere in the system.

Comment: @Peter Wood: I agree. mycheck is not very descriptive name. Will change it

Comment: I wanted an in-place solution without the need of an extra struct.

Comment: Why don't you want the extra struct?

Comment: @oddin It's both readable and reusable, neither of which describe the suggestions in the accepted answer. Readability counts. And re-use reduces verbosity, overall.